# Ommit the tag from the text using golang?

Tags: regex, go

I want to do some template by using golang,and want to ommit some tags from a xml like xlsx.  the xml source like this:

```
  input := `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?> 
  <Worksheet ss:Name="sheet1">
  <Names>
   <NamedRange ss:Name="_FilterDatabase" ss:RefersTo="=sheet!R3C1:R3C13"
    ss:Hidden="1"/>
  </Names>
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="15" ss:ExpandedRowCount="7" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="52.8" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15.45">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="37.200000000000003"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="67.2"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="75.600000000000009"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="71.400000000000006"/>  

   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="12" ss:MergeDown="1" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data
      ss:Type="String">This is a title of the sheet!</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">{{range $prj:=.prj}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="45.449999999999996">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s72"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.PrjName}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.ConstrDept}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.Assumer}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.ReplyNo}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.AnPingNo}}</Data></Cell>   

   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">{{end}}</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table> 
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>`
```

and i want to get as following:

1. {{range $prj:=.prj}}

   in this row,i only want to get the "`{{range $prj:=.prj}}`",and ommit the tag around the "`<Row>`"

2.

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">{{end}}</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

in the row, i only want to get the "`{{end}}`",and ommit the tag around the "`<Row>`"

3. any other tag ,i want to remain.  how to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use (if we discard nested `{{}}`) a regexp like `{{[^}]*?}}` with [`Regexp.FindAllString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString).
[This example](http://play.golang.org/p/bNP26trJqJ) would extract the expected results:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("{{[^}]*?}}")
res := re.FindAllString(input, -1)
for _, s := range res {
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
{{range $prj:=.prj}}
{{$prj.PrjName}}
{{$prj.ConstrDept}}
{{$prj.Assumer}}
...
```

But if the data depends on the context of the structure, then a simple regexp is ill-suited for the task (obligatory reference to "[The Center cannot Hold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/6309)").

A xml Marshall or Decoder would be better: [`pkg/encoding/xml/`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/), using techniques like "[Parse both XML element value and attributes for groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600762/6309)"

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/87bAtRbGpV):

```
type Data struct {
    Type  string `xml:"Type,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type Cell struct {
    StyleID string `xml:"StyleID,attr"`
    Data    Data
}
type Row struct {
    Afh    string `xml:"AutoFitHeight,attr"`
    Height string `xml:"Height,attr"`
    Cells  []Cell `xml:"Cell"`
}
type Column struct{}
type Table struct {
    Rows []Row `xml:"Row"`
}
type Worksheet struct {
    Table Table `xml:"Table"`
}
w := &Worksheet{}
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &w)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", w)
```

That will extract all cells, and you can filter the ones that include the Data you want (one with `{{}}`)

```
&{Table:
    { Rows:[
    {Afh:0 Height: 
    Cells:[
        {StyleID:s63 Data:{Type:String Value:This is a title of the sheet!}}
    ]} 
    {Afh:0 Height: 
    Cells:[
        {StyleID:s69 Data:{Type:String Value:{{range $prj:=.prj}}}} 
        {StyleID:s70 Data:{Type: Value:}}
    ]} 
    {Afh:0 Height:45.449999999999996 
    Cells:[
        {StyleID:s72 Data:{Type: Value:}} 
        {StyleID:s70 Data:{Type:String Value:{{$prj.PrjName}}}} 
        {StyleID:s70 Data:{Type:String Value:{{$prj.ConstrDept}}}} 
        {StyleID:s71 Data:{Type:String Value:{{$prj.Assumer}}}}
    ]} 
    {Afh:0 Height: 
    Cells:[
        {StyleID:s73 Data:{Type:String Value:{{end}}}}
    ]}
]}}
```

Comment: the output should be like this:{{range $prj:=.prj}}   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="45.449999999999996">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s72"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.PrjName}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.ConstrDept}}</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">{{$prj.Assumer}}</Data></Cell></Row>.......{{end}}

Comment: only want to get the " {{range $prj:=.prj}}" and "{{end}}" ,and throw the tag "<Row>" around them. others keep still.

Comment: @user3373877 ok, that is a task for xml parsing then.

Comment: @user3373877 I have added an xml Unmarshal example